# How to filter Twitter API mentions

Tags: ruby, twitter, rubygems

I'm creating a project using the Twitter gem and need to filter the tweets that I receive from `mentions_timeline`.

I thought about filtering through a couple of `if` statements reading the text of the tweet:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'twitter'
require 'sinatra/reloader'

include ERB::Util

before do
  config = {
      :consumer_key => 'xxx',
      :consumer_secret => 'xxx',
      :access_token => 'xxx',
      :access_token_secret => 'xxx'
  }
    @client = Twitter::REST::Client.new(config)
end

get '/order' do
  @tweets = @client.mentions_timeline
  @collect_tweets = Array.new
  @delivery_tweets = Array.new

  @tweets.each do |tweet|
    if (tweet.text.include? "order" && tweet.text.include? "collect")
      @collect_tweets.push(tweet)
    elsif (tweet.text.include? "order" && tweet.text.include? "delivery")
      @delivery_tweets.push(tweet)
    end

  erb :order
end
```

But it won't work.

I'm receiving this error:

```
/Users/me/Projects/team-13/order.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')' rder" && tweet.text.include? "collect") ^ /Users/me/Projects/team-13/order.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')' rder" && tweet.text.include? "delivery") ^ /Users/me/Projects/team-13/order.rb:30: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need just enough code necessary to _run_ and test to duplicate the problem. We also need the minimum supporting data that helps demonstrate it. Without that it wastes our time. SO isn't a "help me" site, as you mentioned, but in order to help others, we need certain things.

Comment: In order to duplicate the problem you would need to have the twitter secret keys, which I'm obviously not going to publish here. I was just wondering if someone that has more expertise on ruby than the little knowledge that I have could see a big syntax error that could be the problem. Anyway, you are right in the sense that I didn't specified the problem itself. Thank you for telling me, I'll edit the post ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few errors in your code.

The first on line 23 and 25 in your code, is that you need parenthesis for the parameter for the `include?` method. You need that when you are listing multiple methods like you are. You can change that to this:

```
if (tweet.text.include?("order") && tweet.text.include?("collect"))
```

The other error on line 30 is that you are missing an `end` for your each loop.

The `each` loop should look something like this:

```
@tweets.each do |tweet|
    if (tweet.text.include?("order") && tweet.text.include?("collect"))
        @collect_tweets.push(tweet)
    elsif (tweet.text.include?("order") && tweet.text.include?("delivery"))
        @delivery_tweets.push(tweet)
    end
end
```

Comment: True, I figured it out after reading the other guys comment and just when I came here to close this I saw your answer. Thank you very much anyway. Appreciate that you took your time answering as good as you did 

Comment: Be careful calling them "brackets" (`[...]`). They're parenthesis (`(...)`). You _could_ call them "square brackets" vs. "round brackets" but commonly they're known as brackets and parenthesis and are not interchangeable for this use. Also, those are methods, not functions.

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing your each block:

```
'order.rb:30: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end'
```

Read the error message and it will tell you where to fix it.

```
   @tweets.each do |tweet|
     if (tweet.text.include? "order" && tweet.text.include? "collect")
      @collect_tweets.push(tweet)
     elsif (tweet.text.include? "order" && tweet.text.include? "delivery")
      @delivery_tweets.push(tweet)
     end
   end
```

Comment: True! Thank you very much! I guess I just need to read the errors better... haha